# Foreign Key field won't update when inserting new values using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, foreign-keys

I'm having problems with inserting new data into two different tables using Laravel.

This is the second table showing it's primary and foreign key:

[image: secondTableData]

As you can see, the second field should be linked with the first table which you are seeing below this:

[image: primaryKey]

The code for the model:

[image: modelCode]

That was before signed with "nullable" but when I tried to insert data the column was always empty of course.

I used the "hasMany()" and "belongsTo()" functions and they should work.

This is the "hasMany()":

[image: hasMany]

And this is the "belongsTo()":

[image]

This is the code of the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Sostanze;
use App\Models\DatiForm;

class DatiFormController extends Controller
{

    public function showForm(){
        return view('formVersioneFlexbox');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        DB::beginTransaction();

        try{

            $datiForm = DatiForm::create([

                'cognome' => $request->input('cognome'),
                'nome' => $request->input('nome'),
                'ricostruzione' => $request->input('ricostruzione'),
                'motivazione' => $request->input('motivazione'),
                'soggetto' => $request->input('soggetto'),
                'sostanza' => $request->input('sostanza'),
                'svolgimentoValues' => $request- `>input('svolgimentoValues'),`
                'checkValutazioni' => $request->input('checkValutazioni'),
                'giudiziaValues' => $request->input('giudiziaValues'),
                'checkQuintoComma' => $request->input('checkQuintoComma'),
                'circostanze' => $request->input('circostanze'),
                'aggravataBase' => $request->input('aggravataBase'),
                'reiterataBase' => $request->input('reiterataBase'),
                'sussistenza' => $request->input('sussistenza'),
                'chckboxCont' => $request->input('chckboxCont'),
                'si_no' => $request->input('si_no'),
                'calcoloPena' => $request->input('calcoloPena'),
                'chckboxAccessori' => $request->input('chckboxAccessori'),
                'revocaMisura' => $request->input('revocaMisura')
            ]);

            $datiSostanze = Sostanze::create([

                'sostanza' => $request->input('sostanza'),
                'analisi' => $request->input('analisi'),
                'principio_attivo' => $request->input('principio_attivo'),
                'dosi_grammi' => $request->input('dosi_grammi'),
                'dosi_medie' => $request->input('dosi_medie')
            ]);

            DB::commit();

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Dati salvati con successo'], 200);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Si è verificato un errore durante il salvataggio dei dati'], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Sostanze's model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\DatiForm;

class Sostanze extends Model

{
protected $table = 'sostanze';

protected $casts = [
    'sostanza' => 'array'
];

protected $fillable = [
    'sostanza', 'analisi', 'principio_attivo',
    'dosi_grammi', 'dosi_medie'
];

public function dati_form(){
    return $this->belongsTo(DatiForm::class, 'id_utente');
}

}
```

DatiForm's model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Sostanze;

class DatiForm extends Model
{
protected $table = 'dati_form';

protected $casts = [
    'sostanza' => 'array',
    'checkValutazioni' => 'array',
    'checkQuintoComma' => 'array',
    'chckboxCont' => 'array',
    'chckboxAccessori' => 'array'
];

protected $fillable = [
    'cognome', 'nome', 'ricostruzione',
    'motivazione', 'soggetto', 'sostanza',
    'svolgimentoValues', 'checkValutazioni',
    'giudiziaValues', 'checkQuintoComma',
    'circostanze', 'aggravataBase', 'reiterataBase',
    'sussistenza', 'chckboxCont', 'si_no',
    'calcoloPena', 'chckboxAccessori', 'revocaMisura'
];

public function sostanze(){
    return $this->hasMany(Sostanze::class);
}

}
```

I want to fill it with the ID of the user from the first table, I can't find anything to solve it, any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Please include code that you wrote in controller and your model too. It will help readers to understand the issue.

Comment: Please fill all params when defining relations. Some may say I'm wrong. But do it. Do not let laravel guess your link columns. You are using id_ for primary and also foreign key . I guess that is the issue. Also you arenot calling any relation in your controller. Attach is a function that can link 2 models via a pivot table.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel all the fields are protected for mass assignment. Put **id_utente** in fillable.

Insert a record into the DatiForm table

```
$datiForm = DatiForm::create([

            'cognome' => $request->input('cognome'),
            'nome' => $request->input('nome'),
            'ricostruzione' => $request->input('ricostruzione'),
            'motivazione' => $request->input('motivazione'),
            'soggetto' => $request->input('soggetto'),
            'sostanza' => $request->input('sostanza'),
            'svolgimentoValues' => $request- `>input('svolgimentoValues'),`
            'checkValutazioni' => $request->input('checkValutazioni'),
            'giudiziaValues' => $request->input('giudiziaValues'),
            'checkQuintoComma' => $request->input('checkQuintoComma'),
            'circostanze' => $request->input('circostanze'),
            'aggravataBase' => $request->input('aggravataBase'),
            'reiterataBase' => $request->input('reiterataBase'),
            'sussistenza' => $request->input('sussistenza'),
            'chckboxCont' => $request->input('chckboxCont'),
            'si_no' => $request->input('si_no'),
            'calcoloPena' => $request->input('calcoloPena'),
            'chckboxAccessori' => $request->input('chckboxAccessori'),
            'revocaMisura' => $request->input('revocaMisura')
        ]);
```

Retrieve the ID of the inserted record from DatiForm

```
     $datiFormId = $datiForm->id;
```

Save data in the Sostanze table

```
      $datiSostanze = Sostanze::create([
            'id_utente' => $datiFormId,
            'sostanza' => $request->input('sostanza'),
            'analisi' => $request->input('analisi'),
            'principio_attivo' => $request->input('principio_attivo'),
            'dosi_grammi' => $request->input('dosi_grammi'),
            'dosi_medie' => $request->input('dosi_medie')
        ]);
```